# Firestore: Unsubscribe from valueChanges (user gets "Missing permissions" when signing out)

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to unsubscribe from a valueChanges() ?
When my users sign in, I fetch their user data like this

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.flatMap(authUser => {
  if (!authUser) {
    this.user = null;
    return Observable.of(this.user);
  }

  return this.db.doc<UserServerData>(`users/${authUser.uid}`)
    .valueChanges()
    .map(user => new User(authUser.uid, user));
});
```

Of course I have a rule on Firestore saying that only the user with a specific id can read this user datas...
So when a user signs out, every queries with a rule on the user id fail and I get a "Missing permissions" error.

So here's my question, how should I do this ? 
Is there a way to unsubscribe from a query ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire author here.

You have two options. Either return an empty set for logged out users or use a route guard.

Returning an empty set is easy. Replace `.of(null)` with an empty array.

```
this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.switchMap(authUser => {
  if (!authUser) {
    this.user = null;
    return Observable.of(null);
  }
  return this.db.doc<UserServerData | null>(`users/${authUser.uid}`)
    .valueChanges()
    .map(user => new User(authUser.uid, user));
});
```

[Using a route guard is a bit more complicated](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) and requires a dependency on the `@angular/router`. However, it will ensure that the user exists before the route loads.

Comment: Hi David. Thanks. Why should I return an array since I'm querying a doc, not a collection ? Anyway I've tried it and Typescript fails on compile because my Observable is expecting a "User" type of data (`user$: Observable<User>`) and I'm trying to give him an empty array. Also I'm using Ionic, so no angular router for me. Since I'm in a switchMap, are we sure the Firestore query is not triggered by the authState change ? Thanks again (Love the Firecasts)

Comment: Good point! I updated it to allow a null value OR a User. It depends on your template however. I recommend using the null suppression operator (?) to work around this.

Comment: Sorry David. Sadly, that does not fix the issue. We tell the query it can now return null, but still it will try to fetch the user at `users/UID` so we still get a "Missing or insufficient permissions" error. I thought the check on `authUser` would be enough but it looks like the connection with Firestore is made anyway in the switchMap. Maybe that's the issue ? Should I catch the  error somewhere to avoid the Runtime error ?

Comment: My bad. It works with the switchMap. I didn't notice I was using flatMap and you were using switchMap in your example. Thanks a lot